# Baseline alignment of shaded side notes in the memoir class

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir, marginpar

I'm using the `memoir` class, and I'd like to add a shaded background to my sidenotes. My solution, however, doesn't work: the baseline of the sidenote text and the body text no longer align, as illustrated by my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
Lorem
\sidepar[\textit{Note.}]{}
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris.

Lorem
\sidepar[\begin{snugshade} \textit{Note.} \end{snugshade}]{}
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I understand that there may be solutions provided by other packages, but I'd also like to understand why the position of the note shifts.

Comment: What about `\sidepar[\colorbox{shadecolor}{\textit{Note.}}]{}`?

Comment: @Werner Well, that was easy! What a nice, simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a coloured box inside your `\sidepar`, then you can use `\colorbox{shadecolor}{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
Lorem
\sidepar[\textit{Note.}]{}
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris.

Lorem
\sidepar[\begin{snugshade} \textit{Note.} \end{snugshade}]{}
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris.

Lorem
\sidepar[\colorbox{shadecolor}{\textit{Note.}}]{}
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris.

\end{document}
```